# Spark: foreachRDD only gets executed when terminating the Application

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Our Spark Application is supposed to run the method „foreachRDD“  every 1 Second (The Batch Duration). The problem is that the method executes just once, when the application gets terminated. Why is that so? In python it works as expected. We dont have a clue why its not working as we expect it to.

I know that this code is not optimized at all (redis connection etc.) thats not the point :)

```
public class Client {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local");
        conf.setAppName("TwitterStreamApp");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        sc.setLogLevel("ERROR");
        //Duration duration = new Duration(1000);
        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, Durations.seconds(1));
        JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> datastream = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost",9009);


        JavaDStream<String> words = datastream.flatMap(x->Arrays.asList(x.split(" ")).iterator());
        JavaPairDStream<String,Integer> hashtags = words
                .filter(x-> x.contains("#"))
                .mapToPair(x-> new Tuple2<>(x,1))
                .reduceByKey((a,b)->a+b);

        hashtags.foreachRDD((VoidFunction<JavaPairRDD<String,Integer>>) rdd -> {
            rdd.foreach((VoidFunction<Tuple2<String,Integer>>) s -> {
                JedisPool pool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "localhost");
                Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();
                jedis.select(0);
                String word = s._1();
                String count = s._2().toString();
                System.out.println(word + " "+ count);
                if(jedis.exists(word)){
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(jedis.get(word));
                    jedis.set(word, Integer.toString(i+s._2()));
                }else{
                    jedis.set(word, count);
                }
            });
            System.out.println("--------New RDD--------");
        });

        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();
    }

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is the data source? Does it constantly updated with new elements?

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much, the Data source is the Twitter API and yeah it’s getting constantly new strings :)

Comment: Hi @RobertKossendey. I am having similar observation, where .foreachRDD() runs when I terminate the spark process. We are running spark-submit in local mode. Were you able to resolve this ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not..